# minSdkVersion is different than the minimum api level

Tags: android

I'm a little confused! I made an Android app which has these lines of code in the `Gradle` file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.example.ayech0x2.navigationbarforallactivitites"
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 26
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
```

So as you see the minimum version of Android is Lolipop after that I used an app called Install APKs to see my `apk` pieces of information I found that the minimum API level is 3 (Cupcake)! what did this mean? What's the difference between `minSdkVersion` and `minimum API level`?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minSdkVersion` and `Minimum API Level` refers the same thing. If you are specifying the minSdkVersion as 21, the app will not get installed on the device with API level below 21.

Something might be wrong with the app checking the minimum API level of your app.

You can verify it yourself by trying to install the app in the devices below the specified API level.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I've already noticed that sometimes before running the app some emulators are disabled because their API is inferior to 21, But what do think about this i mean where can be the problem

Comment: I don't think you should worry about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude :)

Answer (score 3):

The **minSdkVerison** and minimum API level is same. You cannot install the apk on an Android OS of api level below minimum api level. the apk checking tool may have some problem in checking the details.

Answer (score 1):

**minSdkVersion:** is the minimum version of the `Android OS` required to run your application.

**Minimum API Level:** is also the same as **minSdkVersion**

I think which app you used **Install APKs** isn't working properly.