# What's the oldest SDK i can target on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, storage, abi

I currently have this in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
```

which translates into `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

This is because i'm dealing with devices running Androids as old as Lollipop.
The apps i'm currently maintaining use `/sdcard/` as medium to interchange and store some data.

With scoped storage, if targeting Android 11, then the only way i can keep this behavior is to add [preserveLegacyExternalStorage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#preserveLegacyExternalStorage) to [requestLegacyExternalStorage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app). For now.

While i'm not targeting Android 11 (API 30), what's the minimum API it will support? I can find info on Google Play's requirements, but these apps are installed directly, not via a marketplace.

[This blogpost](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) seems to imply there is no minimum but i find that un-Google-like and it's not an official source.

(Yes i'm in the process of migrating away from using `/sdcard/`).

Comment: Possible dupe: [minSdkVersion is different than the minimum api level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46928699/295004)

Answer (score 0):

> With scoped storage, if targeting Android 11, then the only way i can keep this behavior is to add preserveLegacyExternalStorage to requestLegacyExternalStorage. For now.

Only on Android 11 and higher devices. Older devices behave as they did.

> While i'm not targeting Android 11 (API 30), what's the minimum API it will support?

You are declaring that your apps support back to API Level 19. Either you are correct or you are not. We cannot tell, because we do not have access to the entire code of your apps. Beyond that, we are having to guess what "it" means  in "it will support".

> This blogpost seems to imply there is no minimum

The `minSdk` / `minSdkVersion` is the minimum. *You* declare what the minimum is that you are willing to support. Numerically, the lowest minimum is API Level 1, representing Android 1.0.

> and it's not an official source

That is Google's official Medium site for developer relations, and Ian Lake is a Google engineer. By most measures, that would make it an official source.

> What's the oldest SDK i can target on Android?

API Level 1. This is pointless due to the small number of devices running Android 1.0. And it will interfere with your development work, as most of the Android SDK is newer than that, and you would not be able to use those newer APIs (or use libraries that depend on those newer APIs).

> these apps are installed directly, not via a marketplace.

If you know the devices the apps are installed upon, you know the Android OS version that those devices run, and therefore you know what your `minSdk` should be.

Comment: Ok, TL;DR question then: assuming i don't migrate away from `/sdcard/`, how can i ensure my apps work on Android 11 devices when Google deprecates `preserveLegacyExternalStorage` and `requestLegacyExternalStorage.`? And when will that be? I can support minimum API 1 all i want but my apps will break sooner or later.

Comment: @vesperto: "how can i ensure my apps work on Android 11 devices when Google deprecates preserveLegacyExternalStorage and requestLegacyExternalStorage.?" -- they will not work. The closest thing would be to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` in all the apps and ask the user to select the same tree. "And when will that be?" -- two years ago.